# How to uninstall iTerm2

Tags: uninstallation, iterm2

After searching for about an hour and only getting install options, I have to ask:  How to uninstall iTerm2?

So, somehow, I passed a big load of JSON into it (don't ask) and now it has lost the plot somewhat.  So I want to kill it and start over, profile and all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To completely remove in using terminal:

1. Quit the app.
2. Open Terminal and execute the following.

```
sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist

sudo rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2

sudo rm -r /Applications/iTerm.app
```

Comment: Thanks! Deleting iTerm2 from application support removed the options to "Open with iTerm2" when i right-click on a directory in Finder (2nd command in the answer). Don't know what that `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` file do, but deleted it anyway (1st command in the answer).

Comment: New users beware of using `rm` on anything frivolously. Especially with `sudo` in front.

Answer (score 35):

- If it's installed by Homebrew then you could use `brew cask uninstall iterm2`.
- If it's installed by a manually downloaded DMG file then
  you could goto the `/Applications` folder in Finder, find the iTerm
  Icon, right-click it and then `move to trash`.

Comment: I tried removing the Application to Trash as well as installing the brew cask and then uninstalling it using the command line. Neither of them fully uninstalled iTerm2 [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727747/712334).

Comment: What if you didn't install through brew? but by downloading iTerm2.app?

Comment: It would not remove iterm settings or others. We maybe need more strictly way

Comment: I also downloaded iterm2.app from the app's main website. No DMG.

Comment: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command.

Answer (score 15):

Moving iTerm2 from *Applications* to *Trash* or performaning a `brew uninstall --cask iterm2` may not be enough as it leaves behind Finder Context Menu Items:

[image]

There's [FAQ entry](https://iterm2.com/faq.html) covering how to remove all settings:

```
defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2
```

However, running the above command does not remove the items from the Finder Context Menu even after a `killall Finder`.

I opened an issue on the iTerm repo on GitLab:
 https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/8459.

Look there for updates on how to uninstall iTerm2 *completely*.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use the free drag-and-drop [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) app

Doing so will locate and remove all iTerm files like so:

[image: AppCleaner]

Comment: Hi Chris. Does the application you are recommending also remove the Finder Context Menu Items (please see related answer on this page)? Thank you. 

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to test this out due to how heavily configured my current iTerm setup is. However if you or someone else would like to try this out I'm sure the answer would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Search iterm globally to ensure that all executable programs named iterm on your Mac are deleted. Then right-click the context menu and select open with iterm once. At this time, it will report an error. Click OK. Right click again to view the context menu, and you will find that iterm has disappeared from your list.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this issue.
Whatever I tried I still have an option for iTerm in right-click.
In the end, I needed to delete the Iterm application also from the download folder.
Then use the free app cleaner to delete all related to the app.
https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Comment: This is *basically* the same as [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67524898/4424636)